# Joomla contact form: How to fix/edit bugged tooltip?

Tags: joomla3.0

For the Joomla contact form (using Joomla 3.3.3), you have your required fields and a tooltip that shows if you mouse over the field name. Fx. the field "Name" the tooltip I suppose would show "Your name"

But instead it shows this: "< strong >Name< /strong >< br/ >Your name"?

How to remove the "< strong >Name< /strong > "?

Have tried looking around a bit but haven't really found a solution to this yet. Only how to remove/hide the tooltips, but not how to fix it removing those code strings.

Screenshot of my contact form:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4dxsst0u91gcan/Contact%20tooltip%20issue.png?dl=0

Okay figured that the problem is coming from my template. 
Tried switching over to the joomla protostart template and test it there, and the tooltip work fine.

So now I need to figure out why it isn't working on the template I'm currently using.

Comment: In the example, are you using custom language files or form XML definition file?

Comment: No, in the example I am using the en-GB language pack that comes with Joomla.

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually render the page?

Comment: I'm not so sure, but this is a link to our contact page: http://www.evf.fo/samband-vidh-evf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a jquery conflict with joomla updates.

Fixed it by editing the var.php in my template with the following changes:

From, (line 7):

```
JHTML::_('behavior.framework', true);
// disabled sins joomla 3
//JHTML::_( 'behavior.mootools' );
```

To:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');               // JOOMLA 3.X    (LOADS BOOTSTRAP)
JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);

$doc->addScript($this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/jquery_no_conflict.js', 'text/javascript'); 
// disabled sins joomla 3
//JHTML::_( 'behavior.mootools' );
```

And removed this on line 28.

```
// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```